# Debug JS that works in Chrome but not FF or IE

Tags: jquery

The following code works fine in Chrome but does nothing in FF and IE. How can I debug this? The way that Im developing locally means I cant make my code publicly accessible.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       // alert('dfd');
        $('#mobileMenuLink a').click(function () {
            event.preventDefault();
            // alert('dfd');
            $('#menu').toggleClass('mobileMenuOpen');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is `event`? Maybe you just missed a parameter declaration:

```
$('#mobileMenuLink a').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#menu').toggleClass('mobileMenuOpen');
});
```

Comment: Why was the 'event' required? I normally dont use it and things work fine and its not in this example. Thanks  http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: Ive asked this as a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13823142/when-does-jquery-click-function-need-an-event

Answer (score 0):

To debug on FireFox, download FireBug. It will give you the ability to observe the console and check if any errors are thrown. You can also use it to debug your JS code.

The same can be said about IE, using F12, you can use the built-in developer tool.