# When does jQuery click function need an 'event'?

Tags: jquery

I had a click function with jquery which didnt work until I added the 'event' (see below).

When is the event needed? This documentation doenst use it: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Didnt work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#div a').click(function () {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#menu,#wrapper').toggleClass('open');
        });
    })
```

Works:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#div a').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#menu,#wrapper').toggleClass('open');
        });
    })
```

Comment: Otherwise where is the `event` variable (e.g., used in `event.preventDefault();`) being created?

Comment: First person to answer with a solution and an explanation of why it's significant gets my upvote

Comment: @MikeRobinson What more do you need than "if you don't define the variable you can't call a method on the variable" ?

Comment: @dystoy I think the Mike is suggesting that it would be most helpful for the OP to see an explanation of *what* the event object actually is and what it is used for. (e.g., provide a general answer to the OP's question of "When is the `event` needed?")

Comment: @apsillers A far more eloquent explanation than I could have provided, thank you

Comment: Wow that certainly changed things. Upvotes for everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation you link to precises that the `click` function is a shortcut for [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) with eventType being `"click"`. Here's an extract of this documentation :

> .bind( eventType [, eventData], handler(eventObject) )

The prototype of the bind function shows that `handler`, the callback you provide, receives an `eventObject`, which is the event you have in your code.

This event is a jQuery wrapped event, having the function you call, `preventDefault`.

So this line

```
event.preventDefault();
```

needs the event to be defined. Writing `function(event)` in the declaration of your function declares the local variable event whose value will be the one of the `eventObject` given by jQuery.

Alternatively, if you don't like defining variables, you could do this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#div a').click(function () {
        $('#menu,#wrapper').toggleClass('open');
        return false; // this prevents default handling and also stops propagation
    });
})
```

Answer (score 2):

As you noted, the jquery documentation explains the method and its signature, but doesn't give an example of using the eventObject.

```
.click( handler(eventObject) )

handler(eventObject) A function to execute each time the event is triggered.
```

You are supplying an anonymous function in place of the handler(eventObject):

```
function() {
// do something
}
```

but the function signature includes the eventObject that you can work with

```
function(event) {
// do something with event, such as event.preventDefault();
}
```

Note that you could also call a named function, if that helps with your understanding:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#div a').click(handleSomeClick);
    })

function handleSomeClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#menu,#wrapper').toggleClass('open');
}
```

It may be useful for you to console.log(event) to see what else you can do with this object.

Answer (score 2):

Your listener function is being passed an *event object* when the `click` event fires. In your first example, your function doesn't accept any parameters and doesn't otherwise define `event`, and so the `event` in `event.preventDefault` is not defined.

But let's back up a bit:

In JavaScript, when event listener function are fired, they are passed an [*event object*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event#DOM_Event_interface) as their first argument. This event object contains detailed specifics about the event that just occurred, e.g., which key was pressed for a `keydown` event or which mouse button was used (left, right, middle) for a `click` event.

The event object also has a few special functions for controlling the event, including `event.preventDefault`, which stops the default browser behavior. For example, when you bind a `click` listener to a link `<a>` element (as you do here), you may want to stop the browser from actually following the link, which is the default browser reaction to clicked links.

In terms of jQuery specifically, the event object is standardized for cross-browser use, but otherwise everything I've said above about plain JS also applies. You can see the specs for the [jQuery event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) in the jQuery docs.

**tl;dr:** You want your function to be able to use `event.preventDefault`. In order to do that, you must have your event listener function accept the *event object* from the event and then call its `.preventDefault` method.

Answer (score 2):

In your code snippet that doesn't work, `event` is undefined because you didn't declare it or accept it as a parameter to the function.

```
$(element).click(function(event){ // "event" is optional, but required if you intend to use it
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

You only *"need"* to pass the event object parameter if you intend to use the event object, such as using it to prevent the default action in your code or getting information from it such as which element the event originated from.

Note also that you can use whatever name you want in place of event and it will still work.

```
$(element).click(function(foobar){
    foobar.preventDefault();
    alert("The id of the clicked element is: " + foobar.target.id);
});
```

If you are unsure, just include it anyway, it won't harm anything.

Answer (score 0):

because you use   `event`  `event.preventDefault();` you have to pass it as a parameter , but in normal cases it's optional